# R fatal error with gpuR

Tags: r, gpu

I am trying to learn how to use a gpu for calculations or analysis hands on. My recently acquired PC has an NVIDIA GeForce 1060 GTX with 6GB of RAM. I have downloaded and installed the NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit.

I am trying to get familiar with gpuR. When I try to use a function like gpuMatrix(rnorm(16), nrow = 4, ncol = 4) R experiences a fatal error and crashes.

I have had success using tensorflow-gpu with Python 3.6.1, so I know the GPU is active.

Code, device, environment, and system info is below. 
Note: OS is Windows 10.

What am I missing? Thanks!

```
    > `library(gpuR)`

    Number of platforms: 1
    - platform: NVIDIA Corporation: OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 8.0.0
      - gpu index: 0
        - GeForce GTX 1060 6GB
    checked all devices
    completed initialization
    gpuR 1.2.3

    Attaching package: ‘gpuR’

    The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

        colnames, norm, pmax, pmin, svd

    > `library(devtools)`
    > `gpuInfo()`
    $deviceName
    [1] "GeForce GTX 1060 6GB"

    $deviceVendor
    [1] "NVIDIA Corporation"

    $numberOfCores
    [1] 10

    $maxWorkGroupSize
    [1] 1024

    $maxWorkItemDim
    [1] 3

    $maxWorkItemSizes
    [1] 1024 1024   64

    $deviceMemory
    [1] 6442450944

    $clockFreq
    [1] 1708

    $localMem
    [1] 49152

    $maxAllocatableMem
    [1] 1610612736

    $available
    [1] "yes"

    $deviceExtensions
     [1] "cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics"          "cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics" "cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics"     
     [4] "cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics"  "cl_khr_fp64"                           "cl_khr_byte_addressable_store"       
     [7] "cl_khr_icd"                           "cl_khr_gl_sharing"                    "cl_nv_compiler_options"              
    [10] "cl_nv_device_attribute_query"         "cl_nv_pragma_unroll"                  "cl_nv_d3d10_sharing"                 
    [13] "cl_khr_d3d10_sharing"                 "cl_nv_d3d11_sharing"                  "cl_nv_copy_opts"                     

    $double_support
    [1] TRUE

    > `currentDevice()`
    $device
    [1] "GeForce GTX 1060 6GB"

    $device_index
    [1] 1

    $device_type
    [1] "gpu"

    > `currentPlatform()`
    $platform
    [1] "NVIDIA Corporation: OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 8.0.0"

    $platform_index
    [1] 1

    > `devtools::session_info()`
    Session info ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     setting  value                       
     version  R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
     system   x86_64, mingw32             
     ui       RStudio (1.0.153)           
     language (EN)                        
     collate  English_United States.1252  
     tz       America/Phoenix             
     date     2017-08-13                  

    Packages ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     package              * version date       source                         
     assertive              0.3-5   2016-12-31 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
     assertive.base         0.0-7   2016-12-30 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
     assertive.code         0.0-1   2015-10-06 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
     assertive.data         0.0-1   2015-10-06 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
     assertive.data.uk      0.0-1   2015-10-06 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
     assertive.data.us      0.0-1   2015-10-06 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
     assertive.datetimes    0.0-2   2016-05-10 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
     assertive.files        0.0-2   2016-05-10 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
     assertive.matrices     0.0-1   2015-10-06 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
     assertive.models       0.0-1   2015-10-06 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
     assertive.numbers      0.0-2   2016-05-09 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
     assertive.properties   0.0-4   2016-12-30 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
     assertive.reflection   0.0-4   2016-12-30 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
     assertive.sets         0.0-3   2016-12-30 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
     assertive.strings      0.0-3   2016-05-10 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
     assertive.types        0.0-3   2016-12-30 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
     base                 * 3.4.1   2017-06-30 local                          
     codetools              0.2-15  2016-10-05 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
     compiler               3.4.1   2017-06-30 local                          
     datasets             * 3.4.1   2017-06-30 local                          
     devtools             * 1.13.3  2017-08-02 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
     digest                 0.6.12  2017-01-27 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
     gpuR                 * 1.2.3   2017-08-13 Github      (cdeterman/gpuR@de6d377)
     graphics             * 3.4.1   2017-06-30 local                          
     grDevices            * 3.4.1   2017-06-30 local                          
     knitr                  1.17    2017-08-10 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
     memoise                1.1.0   2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
     methods              * 3.4.1   2017-06-30 local                          
     Rcpp                   0.12.12 2017-07-15 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                 
     stats                * 3.4.1   2017-06-30 local                          
     stringi                1.1.5   2017-04-07 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                 
     tools                  3.4.1   2017-06-30 local                          
     utils                * 3.4.1   2017-06-30 local                          
     withr                  2.0.0   2017-07-28 CRAN (R 3.4.1)
```

Comment: The code works on my Nvidia Quadro 2000 graphics card. Try to reinstall `gpuR` following the instruction given here: https://github.com/cdeterman/gpuR/wiki

Comment: I re-installed gpuR a couple times from CRAN and it appears to work now. I was using the github version - perhaps that was the issue? Thank you for the productive feedback!

Comment: Some months ago I contacted the developer of `gpuR` and he suggested me to use only the "developer" version on github.

Comment: @MarcoSandri that would be because I am trying to finish a bunch of new features.  Once those are settled I will release the new version to CRAN.  The risk with `develop` is that it is 'develop' so it is likely to have additional unknown bugs until I have sufficiently tested everything.

Comment: @Biscuit, please feel free to submit any issues related to the `gpuR` package on the [github](https://github.com/cdeterman/gpuR/issues) and I will make sure to address them.

Comment: @cdeterman Thank you for your great work !

Comment: @Biscuit, was this ever resolved?  I can't remember which issue this would refer to if not.